# Trouble shrinking my regex to find defined groups

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to make a regex that parses the following structure, as an example of input:

> insert {wine: Chateau Ste, year: 1997, origin: France, value: 500.00, qtt: 3}

I was able to achieve this wit the following code:

```
String line = "insert {wine: Chateau Ste, year: 1997, origin: France, value: 500.00, qtd: 3}";
String pattern = "(^[a-zA-Z]+) \\{(\\w+): (.+), (\\w+): (.+), (\\w+): (.+), (\\w+): (.+), (\\w+): (.+)}";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

if (m.find()) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(3) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(4) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(5) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(6) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(7) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(8) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(9) );
} else {
      System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

As the output, I get:

```
Found value: insert {wine: Chateau Ste, year: 1997, origin: France, value: 500.00, qtd: 3}
Found value: insert
Found value: wine
Found value: Chateau Ste
Found value: year
Found value: 1997
Found value: origin
Found value: France
Found value: value
Found value: 500.00
```

However, this pattern seems overly repetitive and cumbersome. How could I make it more compact?

I tried the following:

```
String pattern = "(^[a-zA-Z]+) \\{(([a-zA-Z]+): (.+), ){3}(\\w+): (.+)}";
```

but it gives me strange results and an exception in the end:

```
Found value: insert {wine: Chateau Ste, year: 1997, origin: France, value: 500.00, qtd: 3}
Found value: insert
Found value: value: 500.00, 
Found value: value
Found value: 500.00
Found value: qtd
Found value: 3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 7
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Unknown Source)
    at testes.Teste.main(Teste.java:33)
```

Comment: do you want to just split the words?

Comment: Well, basically, yes, following this structure. I'm interesting in getting the output that I'm getting with the working regex. Do you think it'd be easier by not using a regex at all? I'd like to throw an error if the input doesn't follow the given example structure, that's why I went with regex.

Comment: if the values doesn't contains , and : just replace them with space and split by \\s+ should work

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
String line = "insert {wine: Chateau Ste, year: 1997, origin: France, value: 500.00, qtd: 3}";
line = line.replaceAll("\\{"," ").replaceAll(":", " ").replaceAll(","," ").replaceAll("\\}"," ").trim();
for(String s:line.split("\\s+"))
     System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Mm, I guess that works ok. However, with this method, is there any way to analyze the string to make sure that the user entered the *exact syntax* and didn't forget let's say a `,` or something like that, thus throwing an error?

Comment: you can't validate your input by this. This is just to split the words. If you want to validate the input may have to write a regex